# Repeated percent string in makefile target

Tags: makefile, build

I would like to represent targets and dependencies of the following form:

```
dir_MODULE/target_MODULE: dep_MODULE
```

However, the intuitive solutions do not work:

```
dir_%/target_%: dep_%
    @echo 1
dir_%/target_$*: dep_%
    @echo 2

> make: *** No rule to make target `dir_test/target_test'. Stop.
```

Is there a workaround that does not depend on having a list of the possible values of MODULE in advance?

(This is not a duplicate of [Can I have more than one % sign in a makefile target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035930/can-i-have-more-than-one-sign-in-a-makefile-target), because they wanted to generate targets of the form `dir_STR1/target_STR2` for the set of all possible `(STR1,STR2)` tuples; my case is simpler because of the constraint that `STR1 = STR2`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, and simple in principle, but due to Make's lack of regex ability, the only solution (that I can see) is ugly.

You can catch the target with a ["match anything" rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules), write a new rule for that target into a separate file (`special.mk`), then rerun Make with that rule:

```
-include special.mk

special.mk: # not really necessary, but it soothes Make
    @:

ruler = dir_$(1)/target_$(1): dep_$(1)

%:
    @echo $(call ruler,$(subst target_,,$(notdir $@))) > special.mk
    @echo '\t'@echo now building '$@' somehow from $$^ >> special.mk
    @$(MAKE) $@
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to use [eval function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function) along with a recipe template

```
MODULES = mod1 mod2

define MODULE_RULE
dir_$(1)/target_$(1):dep_$(1)
    touch $$@
endef

$(foreach mod,$(MODULES),$(eval $(call MODULE_RULE,$(mod))))
```

For every item in `MODULES`, an explicit rule will be generated that follows the pattern `dir_MODULE/target_MODULE: dep_MODULE`. It is a very convenient way to construct multiple rules that follow a specific pattern but not easily addressed with a simple `%`-rule.

EDIT:

If the list of module is not previously known and should be determined by scanning all `dep` names, then simply use:

```
MODULES=$(patsubst dep_%,%,$(wildcard dep_*))
```

to get all the module names

Also, if you would like to have all the `dir_XXX/target_XXX` targets to be prerequistes of another target, e.g. `all`, you can reconstruct all `dir_XXX/target_XXX` names from MODULE names as such:

```
DIR_NAMES = $(patsubst %,dir_%/,$(MODULES))
TARGET_NAMES = $(patsubst %,target_%,$(MODULES))
FULLPATH_TARGETS = $(join $(DIR_NAMES),$(TARGET_NAMES))

all: $(FULLPATH_TARGETS)
```

Also, in case `dir_XXX` does not exist previously, you can create another rule to make them. The full makefile may look like the following:

```
MODULES = $(patsubst dep_%,%,$(wildcard dep_*))

DIR_NAMES = $(patsubst %,dir_%/,$(MODULES))
TARGET_NAMES = $(patsubst %,target_%,$(MODULES))
FULLPATH_TARGETS = $(join $(DIR_NAMES), $(TARGET_NAMES))

dir_%:
    mkdir -p $@

define MODULE_RULE
dir_$(1)/target_$(1):dep_$(1) dir_$(1)
    touch $$@
endef 

$(foreach mod,$(MODULES),$(eval $(call MODULE_RULE,$(mod))))

all: $(FULLPATH_TARGETS)
```

Comment: This is useful info, but I specifically asked if there was a solution that didn't involve hard-coding a list of modules.

Comment: which can be very easily done by extending this answer. I thought you got stuck at generating rules, instead of generating module names. Answer edited.

Comment: Your edited answer still requires a list of module names, it's just that they're recorded in the filesystem this time.