# Capture two folders in prerequisite for Makefile's target

Tags: shell, makefile

For my Makefile, my prerequisite is of the form

`$(Root)a/b/c/d/File.source`

and I'd like to target

`a/c.zip`

knowing that there are multiple folders for `a` and `c`, that `b` is fixed, that `d` can vary, but that the source file is always called `File.source`.

Taking inspiration [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644089/repeated-percent-string-in-makefile-target?noredirect=1&lq=1), I've tried

```
As:= $(notdir $(shell find $(Root) -mindepth 1  -maxdepth 1  -type d))

define RULE
$1/%.zip: $1/b/%/*/File.source
    echo "Test"
endef

$(foreach a, $(As), $(eval $(call RULE, $(a))))
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at  https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-wildcard-reclist-of-globs which is really handy at collecting files or directory names from different paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be relatively simple, given the fact [how patterns match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match). Having a rule

```
%.zip: b/%.foo
```

will cause `make a/c.zip` to search for `a/b/c.foo` file. With this in mind we can write a quite simple `Makefile`:

```
$ cat Makefile
# Extract directories that contain File.source files
sourcedirs := $(dir $(wildcard $(ROOT)*/b/*/*/File.source))

# Generate archive names: drop the /b/ part and add .zip extension
archives := $(patsubst %/,%.zip,$(subst /b/,/,$(dir $(sourcedirs:/=))))

%.zip: b/%/*/File.source
        echo Making $@ from $<

all: $(archives)
```

The output:

```
$ find . -name File.source
./a/b/c/d/File.source
./foo/b/bar/baz/File.source
./foo/b/cfg/d/File.source

$ make -s
Making foo/bar.zip from foo/b/bar/baz/File.source
Making foo/cfg.zip from foo/b/cfg/d/File.source
Making a/c.zip from a/b/c/d/File.source
```

Comment: Many, _many_, many thanks. I would never have figured that out, and I still don't fully understand it to be honest. I'm trying to (actually) target  "<something else that does not change>a/c.zip" and could not adapt your code to elegantly deal with that. I've still got a long way to go to understand makefiles!

Answer (score 2):

Let's first find all `File.source` files that match the `$(Root)*/b/*/*/File.source` pattern:

```
FILES := $(shell find $(Root)*/b/* -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name File.source)
```

Then, let's create a macro for each of them (I over-exaggerated the number of intermediate variables for easier understanding, you can simplify a bit, if you wish):

```
# $(1): File.source path
define MY_RULE
$(1)-dirs := $$(subst /, ,$(1))
$(1)-Roota := $$(word 1,$$($(1)-dirs))
$(1)-a := $$(patsubst $$(Root)%,%,$$($(1)-Roota))
$(1)-c := $$(word 3,$$($(1)-dirs))
$(1)-target := $$($(1)-a)/$$($(1)-c).zip

$$($(1)-target): $(1)
    @echo "Test for $$< (target $$@)"
endef
```

And finally, let's call the macro on each `File.source` file:

```
$(foreach f,$(FILES),$(eval $(call MY_RULE,$(f))))
```

All in all, plus a `test` phony default goal for easier testing:

```
FILES := $(shell find $(Root)*/b/* -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name File.source)

.PHONY: test
.DEFAULTGOAL := test

# $(1): File.source path
define MY_RULE
$(1)-dirs := $$(subst /, ,$(1))
$(1)-Roota := $$(word 1,$$($(1)-dirs))
$(1)-a := $$(patsubst $$(Root)%,%,$$($(1)-Roota))
$(1)-c := $$(word 3,$$($(1)-dirs))
$(1)-target := $$($(1)-a)/$$($(1)-c).zip

$$($(1)-target): $(1)
    @echo "Test for $$< (target $$@)"

test: $$($(1)-target)
endef

$(foreach f,$(FILES),$(eval $(call MY_RULE,$(f))))
```

Note: there is a possibility that you have more than one `File.source` file with the same corresponding target, because of the `d` part of your pattern. If this happens GNU make will issue warnings and use only the last encountered rule for each such target. There are ways to raise an error, if you prefer, but as all this is already quite complicated, let's leave it as an exercise on make conditionals.

Comment: Thanks a lot. [Raspy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600525/2657549) seemed simpler and easier to understand to my profane eyes, so I went this way after playing with yours, unsuccessfully, for quite some time!

Comment: You did well. Simple is beautiful. Sorry that my solution did not work as you expected. I'd like to understand why, however. Is it because you wanted *all* `File.source` files under `$(Root)a/b/c` to be prerequisites of `a/c.zip` and not just one of them?

Comment: Please, don't read into it: I was not capable of making just simple changes to your recipe, that I had a hard time understanding, but that's on me. If you really want to make your answer more accessible to complete profane like me, adding a few comments could help, but I can't upvote twice `;-)`.